# Why does `less` not recognize the mouse wheel when stdin is a pipe?

Tags: less, mouse-wheel

I was wondering why my `less` sometimes does not recognize the mouse wheel (my terminal is Konsole). Now I've found a pattern: It seems to work whenever `less`'s STDIN comes directly from the shell (zsh here), e.g.

```
$ less somefile.txt
```

But it does not work when STDIN is a pipe from another program, e.g.

```
$ perl report.pl | less
$ git diff # which implicitly invokes `less`
```

Any idea what I can do about that?

P.S. Whenever anyone of you writes a program, please make sure to give it a Google-able name. Search results for `less mouse wheel` or similar are not helpful.

Comment: googling "less mouse-wheel" on the other hand, *does* produce some apparently useful (or, at least, on-topic) results.

Comment: more/less predates google by about 20 years. It predates the Internet. People solved problems before Google.

Comment: SuperMagic: Not quite. There are numerous users reporting "mouse wheel does not work at all", but no one with this particular pattern.